# Procedure or function 'usp_hotelRoom' expects parameter '@name', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, asp.net, stored-procedures, ado.net

Can somebody help me debug my code?

Basically I have created a stored procedure and I want to call that stored procedure inside my website (ASP.NET).

This code is for my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_hotelRoom
    @country VARCHAR(50),
    @name VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        Room.roomID, Room.roomName, Room.type, Room.capacity, Room.roomSize, 
        Room.description, Room.remarks, Room.services, Room.photo,
        Room.price, Hotel.name 
    FROM
        Room 
    INNER JOIN 
        Hotel ON Hotel.orgEmail = Room.orgEmail 
    WHERE
        country = @country 
        AND Hotel.name = @name;
END

EXEC usp_hotelRoom 'singapore', 'marina bay sands';
```

This code is for calling the stored procedure:

```
public static List<Room> getHotelRoomByCountry(string country, string name)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);

    try
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = con;
        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "usp_hotelRoom";

        var paramname = new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "@country",
            Value = country
        };
        command.Parameters.Add(paramname);

        var paramhotel = new SqlParameter
        {
            ParameterName = "@hotel.name",
            Value = name
        };
        command.Parameters.Add(paramhotel);

        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        List<Room> rooms = null;

        if (reader.HasRows)
            rooms = new List<Room>();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            rooms.Add(
                new Room()
                {
                    RoomID = reader["roomID"].ToString(),
                    RoomName = reader["roomName"].ToString(),
                    Type = reader["type"].ToString(),
                    Capacity = reader["capacity"].ToString(),
                    RoomSize = reader["roomSize"].ToString(),
                    Desc = reader["description"].ToString(),
                    Remarks = reader["remarks"].ToString(),
                    Services = reader["services"].ToString(),
                    Pictures = reader["photo"].ToString(),
                    Price = reader["price"].ToString(),
                });
        }
        reader.Close();
        return rooms;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Hope someone can help me. I would appreciate it on your work!

I try to do it by myself and doesn't work, until I try to add new class attributes inside of the Room class (`Hotel.Name`)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Change this line of code

```
ParameterName = "@hotel.name"
```

to

```
ParameterName = "@name"
```

Comment: Great to know! You can accept the answer if your issue is resolved